# How to understand end behavior?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider the leading term of the polynomial function. What is the end behavior of the graph?

$$2x^7 – 8x^6 – 3x^5 – 3$$

What are the steps to do this?

I know with polynomial functions it goes from left to right, so would it be down then up?

My reasoning:

Since the term $2x^7$ is the largest term and the exponent is positive the right side of the graph would go up, but I have no clue on how to determine the left side of the graph.

Comment: Well, it seems to be that by "end behaviour" you mean what that polynomial's limit is when $\;x\to\infty\;$ , so yes: it will "go up" to $\;\infty\;$ . Note that in "the other end", it will "go down" to $\;-\infty\;$, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(-x)^7=-(x^7)$, so it will tend to $-\infty$ as $x\to -\infty$. This is true for any polynomial of odd degree, where the leading coefficient is positive.

Answer (score 2):

You can also factor the leading term and look at the function when it goes to infinity:
$ \lim_{x \to \pm\infty}x^7(2 – \frac{8}{x} – \frac{3}{x^2} –\frac{3}{x^7}).$
I think this gives a better intuition of what happens at infinities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to comment on the leading term and how it effects the graph, but if you want to get a complete picture of the graph you should consider carrying out the [first derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_derivative_test) to find the critical points and how the function behaves in the intervals separated by those critical points.